# Using S format to print a class that implements Formattable

Tags: java, interface

I'm learning Java on my own and I've started working with interfaces. I'm using a textbook called Big Java Early Objects by Cay Horstmann. I came across an exercise that is fairly difficult for me to understand. The exercise states:

The System.out.printf method has predefined formats for printing integers, floating-point
   numbers, and other data types. But it is also extensible. If you use the S format, you
   can print any class that implements the Formattable interface. The interface has a
   single method:

```
    void formatTo(Formatter formatter, int flags, int width, int precision)
```

In this exercise, you should make the BankAccount class implement the Formattable interface.
   Ignore the flags and precision and simply format the bank balance, using the given width.
   In order to achieve this task, you need to get an Appendable reference like this:

```
    Appendable a = formatter.out();
```

Appendable is another interface with a method

```
    void append(CharSequence sequence)
```

CharSequence is yet another interface that is implemented by (among others) the String
   class. Construct a string by first converting the bank balance into a string and then
   padding it with spaces so that it has the desired width. Pass that string to the append method.

I've gotten to the point where, in a tester class, I create and instance of a BankAccount object with $1500 dollars in it. A call to `System.out.printf("%s", account)` gives me 1500. However, I am supposed to get the width parameter to add padding and I don't know how to make that work.

Furthermore, the code that I have doesn't make sense to me. I wrote the code following the description of the exercise but I don't know how it works.

```
 public class BankAccount implements Formattable
 {  
    private String name;
    private double balance;

    /**
       Constructs a bank account with a zero balance.
    */
    public BankAccount()
    {   
        this.name = "";
        this.balance = 0;
    }

    /**
        Constructs a bank account with a given balance.
        @param initialBalance the initial balance
     */
    public BankAccount(String name, double initialBalance)
    {   
        this.name = name;
        this.balance = initialBalance;
    }

    /**
        Deposits money into the bank account.
        @param amount the amount to deposit
     */
    public void deposit(double amount)
    {  
        balance = balance + amount;
    }

    /**
        Withdraws money from the bank account.
        @param amount the amount to withdraw
     */
    public void withdraw(double amount)
    {   
        balance = balance - amount;
    }

    /**
        Gets the current balance of the bank account.
        @return the current balance
     */
    public double getBalance()
    {   
        return balance;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void formatTo(Formatter formatter, int flags, int width, int precision)
    {
        Appendable a = formatter.out();

        String padding = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            padding = padding.concat(" ");
        }

        String bankBalance = padding + String.valueOf(getBalance());

        try
        {
            a.append(bankBalance);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The above is my BankAccount class which implements Formattable and defines the formatTo method. I don't understand what `Appendable a = formatter.out`does. And how does a call to `a.append(bankBalance)` allow me to use `System.out.printf(%s, account);` in my tester class.

Below is my tester class.

```
public class FormatTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BankAccount account = new BankAccount("Bob Robert", 1500);

        System.out.printf("%s", account);
    }
}
```

This prints 1500 without any padding. I know there is no padding because the width parameter isn't given an int value. I don't know how to set it though because if I try to do this:

```
public class FormatTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BankAccount account = new BankAccount("Robert Bob", 1500);

        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();

        System.out.printf("%s", account.formatTo(formatter, 0, 5, 0);
    }
}
```

It complains saying

> The method printf(String, Object...) in the type PrintStream is not
>   applicable for the arguments (String, void)

If I can't set the width this way, how would I be able to do it? BTW, the name doesn't really matter. I was trying to format the name in, but decided to stick with just the balance for now.

Comment: try `System.out.printf("%10s", account);`

Comment: @Scary Wombat Thanks! Your comment didn't really answer my question but it made me realize what I was supposed to do. If you care, I can't use the 10 modifier because I didn't implement it yet. So in the BankAccount class, I defined the formatTo method using the width paramter to add padding. It works now, and I have a better idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Have some explanation...

```
 Formatter fmt = new Formatter();
   StockName sn = new StockName("HUGE", "Huge Fruit, Inc.",
                                "Fruit Titanesque, Inc.");
   fmt.format("%s", sn);                   //   -> "Huge Fruit, Inc."
   fmt.format("%s", sn.toString());        //   -> "HUGE - Huge Fruit, Inc."
   fmt.format("%#s", sn);                  //   -> "HUGE"
   fmt.format("%-10.8s", sn);              //   -> "HUGE      "
   fmt.format("%.12s", sn);                //   -> "Huge Fruit,*"
   fmt.format(Locale.FRANCE, "%25s", sn);  //   -> "   Fruit Titanesque, Inc."
```

and also on the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formattable.html).